# Max of $2$ independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let :

- $X_1,X_2$ independent, with same law
- $ Var(X_1)= \sigma^2$, $E(X_1)=0$
- $G$ is their cumulative function
- Let $X= \max(X_1,X_2)$ with cumulative function $F$

We want to show that $E(X)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [1-G(t)]G(t) dt $

---

My attempt :

$F(t)=P(X_1<t, X_2 <t)=P(X_1<t)P(X_2 <t)= G(t)^2$ so $E(X)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t 2 g(t) G(t)$ then do an integration by parts.

Or we can use $EZ= \int_{0}^{\infty}P(Z>t)dt$ but it works only if $Z>0$

$((G-G^2)^{-1})' =- (g -2gG) \frac{1}{  (G-G^2) ^2 } $

Comment: I guess it's better to start with $X^{+} = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{1}(X > t) dt$ and $X^{-} = \int_{-\infty}^0 \mathbb{1}(X \le t) dt$

Comment: $X^{+}=max(X,0)$ How do you show that your expression is equivalent ?

Comment: For example let $X^+ = 10$, then what will it be on the right side? It will be equal to a measure of a segment $[0,a]$ where $X \ge a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X,0)$.
Then $X^+ = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{1}(X>t)dt = \max(a \ge : X \ge a)$ and $X^- = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 \mathbb{1}(X \le t) dt = \min(a \le 0: X > a)$.

Now we have: $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^+ - X^-) = \mathbb{E}(X^+) - \mathbb{E}(X^-) = \ldots = \int_0^{\infty} (1-F(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^0F(x)dx$$

Now for $F(x) = G^2(x)$ we have:

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(\max(X_1,X_2)) = \int_0^{\infty}(1-G(x))(1+G(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 G^2(x)dx$$

From this point it's easy to get your fact.

$Hint$: we have that $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-G(x))G(x) dx + \int_0^\infty (1-G(x))dx -\int_0^\infty G^2(x)dx +$$
$$+\int_{-\infty}^0(1-G(x))G(x)dx -\int_{-\infty}^0(1-G(x))G(x)dx = $$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1-G(x))G(x)dx + R$$

And you need to prove:
$$R = \int_0^{\infty}(1-G(x) )dx - \int_0^{\infty} G^2(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0} (1-G(x))G(x)dx \equiv 0$$

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}(1-G(x) ) dx  - \int_{ - \infty}^0 G^2(x) dx  $  is supposed to be equal to  $\int_{- \infty}^{0}(1-G(x) ) G(x) dx$ . How do I finish ?

Comment: @zestiria you need to add the necessity and sub it. Note that there should be integral over real line.

Comment: I don't see much

Comment: @zestiria you need to add integral parts, which help you to construct your statement. After that you need to sub them and prove that the rest part vanishes.

Comment: The first integral tends to $0$ because it is $EX_1$. What about the 2 others ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove it backwards:

$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(t)[1-G(t)]dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(t)dt-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G^2(t)dt=$$

$$tG(t)\Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tg(t)dt-tG^2(t)\Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2t g(t)G(t)dt=$$

$$\underbrace{t[G(t)-G^2(t)]\Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}}_{=0}-\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[X_1]}_{=0}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2t g(t)G(t)dt$$

1. To prove that the first addend is zero you have only to calculate the limits...it's easy
2. the second addend is zero as per initial statement
3. the third addend is the result. It matches with the same result you correctly calculated by another way...the proof is finished.

Edit: further details on limit calculus:

$$lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{t}{\frac{1}{G-G^2}} \rightarrow-\frac{(G-G)^2}{g-2gG}=0$$

Comment: Thanks. How do you prove that $t G(t) \underset{ t \to \infty}{ \to} 0 $ ?

Comment: @zestira. It is not $tG(t)$ but $t[G-G^2]=+\infty \times 0$.Write it as $\frac{t}{\frac{1}{G-G^2}}$ and apply de l'Hôpital

Comment: I have written the derivative above, I do not find the limit of the denominator.

Comment: @zestiria: have a look at the EDIT in my answer

Comment: $\frac{u(x)}{v(x)} \to \frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}$ here $u(x)=x$ so $u'(x)=1$. But $v(x)= (G-G^2)^{-1}$ so its derivative looks for me different of what you have written. $v'(x)= - ( g -2gG) ( G-G^2)^{-2}$. Would you give more details ?

Comment: @zestiria: I forgot one "G" while writing. Now it's correct

Comment: Thanks.  My derivative is still different. What is wrong ?

Comment: @zestiria: the derivative of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $\frac{-f'}{f^2}$. You have to calculate the derivative of $\frac{t}{\frac{1}{f}}$ thus the result is $-\frac{f^2}{f'}$