# Expectation of max of $2$ symmetric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let :

- $X_1,X_2$ independent, with same law
- $ Var(X_1)= \sigma^2$, $E(X_1)=0$
- $G$ is their cumulative function
- they have a density $g$
- Let $X= \max(X_1,X_2)$ with cumulative function $F$
- We assume that $X_1$ (and $X_2$) have a symmetric law : $\forall z ~~g(z)=g(-z)$

1. We want to show that $E(X^2)= \sigma^2$
2. In the particular case of $X_1$ and $X_2$ follow $N(0, \sigma^2)$ that $EX= \frac{\sigma}{ \sqrt{ \pi}} $

---

My attempt :

$
\begin{align*}
B &=E(X) \\
&= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} 2t g(t) G(t) dt \\
\int_{- \infty}^{0} 2t g(t) G(t) dt &= \int_{ \infty}^{0}  2 u g(-u) G(-u) du \\
                                               &= \int_{ \infty}^{0} 2 u g(u) G(-u) du \\ 
&=\int_{ \infty}^{0} 2 u g(u) (1-G(u) ) du \\ 
&=\int_{0}^{ \infty} 2 u g(u) (G(u)-1 ) du \\ 
B &=E(X) \\
&= \int_{0}^{ \infty} 2 u g(u) (G(u)-1 ) du +  \int_{0}^{ \infty} 2 u g(u)  G(u) du \\
&=  \int_{0}^{ \infty} 2u g(u) [ 2 G(u) -1] du \\
\end{align*}
$

2. The question is done. Can we use a different method ?

$X=\max(X_1,X_2)= \frac{ X_1 + X_2 + |X_1-X_2|}{2}$, if the law is symmetric

and we take the expectation $ E(X)= \frac{ |X_1-X_2|}{2}= \frac{ E|Z|}{2}$ with $Z\sim N(0, 2 \sigma^2)$ or $E(X)= E(|U|)$ with $U\sim N(0,1) \times \sigma \sqrt{2}$ and $E|U|=\sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi}}$

Comment: You assume that they have a density $g$? And symmetric law means $P[X_1 \leq 0] = P[X_1 \geq 0]$?

Comment: I have edited the question. They have a density $g$ and $ \forall z~~g(z)=g(-z)$

Comment: @zestiria that's your third question with the same interior. You can edit your first one to avoid repeats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max of $2$ independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811451/max-of-2-independent-random-variables)

Comment: For the max of $2$ independent variables, I haven't yet solved the hint. I will give it a try. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $X^2=\frac{X_1^2+X_2^2+(X_1-X_2)^2+2X_1|X_1-X_2|+2X_2|X_1-X_2|+2X_1X_2}{4}$, and using the fact that $\mathbb E[X_1 X_2]=0$, you get that $\mathbb E[X^2] = \sigma^2+\frac{\mathbb E[(X_1+X_2) |X_1-X_2|]}{2}$, by symmetry. Now to show that $\mathbb E[(X_1+X_2) |X_1-X_2|]=0$, observe that $X_1 |X_1-X_2|$ and $-X_1 |X_1-X_2|$ have the same distribution by your assumptions, they also have the same distribution as $X_2|X_1-X_2|$ by i.i.dness, so that $\mathbb E[X_2|X_1-X_2|]=\mathbb E[-X_1|X_1-X_2|]$ and so you get $\mathbb E[X^2]=\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much.